# Version handling of Perl in Windows

Tags: perl

Is possible to use different version of Perl without using the SET  or manipulating the environment variable **"PATH"**

I need a mechanism that allows me to work with different version of Perl for different script without affecting the system configuration.
(e.g. I am using Perl ver 5.6.1 for some scripts and perl 5.8.8 for other Perl scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old trick I do when I have two different, but very incompatible versions of Perl I have to use: Use different suffixes:

For example, I have ClearQuest on my system and must use `cqperl` (which is ClearQuest's version of Perl) to execute scripts that manipulate the issues in ClearQuest. Yet, if I have to manipulate SQL data from our database, I have to use my ActivePerl because I can't add in the `DBI` module into `cqperl`.

What I did was associate the `*.pl` suffix with ActivePerl and the `*.cqpl` suffix with `cqperl`. Now, when I execute a script, and it ends in `*.cqpl`, it uses one version of Perl while a script that ends with `*.pl` is executed by another version of Perl.

To associate a suffix with a program, go into a Windows Explorer window and select **Folder Options** from the **Tools** menu. Then, click on the **File Types** tab. Click on the *New* button and create a new extention to associate with the file. Then, select it in the Registered File Types window, and click on the Advanced button on the bottom.

Create an `Open` action, and associate it with the full path name of the Perl you want to execute that suffix. Like this:

```
"C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*
```

The `%*` is important, so you can pass other parameters to your program.

In your case, you could use `*.pl` for Perl 5.8.8 and `*.pl6` for Perl 5.6.

You don't even need to put Perl's `bin` directory in your path. Just type the name of your script and that's it.

Comment: Will this not affect this not affect Perl library inclusion?

Comment: @hemanth, the Perl library search path is compiled into the perl executable (although it may be relative to the location of perl.exe).  (Except for any directories you add using the PERL5LIB or PERLLIB environment variables.)

Comment: I think the converse can also be done. Instead of renaming the Perl scripts, I can rename the perl.exe to XXXperl.exe and call XXXperl.exe

Comment: Sure, but you'll have to have all versions of Perl in your PATH, and make sure you use the correct one. My way, your script suffix will determine the right version of Perl to use, and you don't need to add all the various places where Perl lives in your Path. One of your requirements was not munging your path.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix: use shebang line.

On Windows: when perl is installed, it usually created two executables: perl.exe and perl5.N.M.exe. For ex. in my Strawberry installation I have perl.exe and perl5.10.1.exe. So if both perls are in PATH, you can call them as perl5.6.1 and 5.8.8.
I.e "perl5.6.1 program.pl".

P.S. I'd suggest to upgrade whole environment to 5.12.2 - Perl has many new useful features.

Answer (score 1):

you can always just run your scripts using the perl interpreter of your choice,
let's suppose you have 2 different perls installed in с:/perl_56 and c:/perl_58.

in CMD.exe you can try this:
**c:/perl_56/bin/perl.exe path_to_your_script here**

and
**c:/perl_58/bin/perl.exe path_to_your_script here**

to run scripts through different versions of perl.
unfortunately, you can't use the "shebang" in the beginning of your scripts in windows as you could do on unix systems.

Comment: Unfortunately I would not be knowing the path of my Perl executable at the time of running. In other words I cannot hard code the path of Perl executable.

Comment: well, it seems to me then, that your only option to be 100% sure, that your scripts will run on target system is to compile them into .exe file using the correct version of perl (this way perl includes itself and all the libraries/modules in the archive, which is then automatically extracted to temp dir on target machine. this way you will be able to run your scripts anywhere, where perl is not even installed), like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237286/how-can-i-compile-my-perl-script-so-it-can-be-executed-on-systems-without-perl-in